# Timescaledb in docker is taking much more space than the total table sizes

Tags: timescaledb

I am runnning timescaledb in docker using below commands

```
docker volume create --driver local --name timescale-new --opt type=none --opt device=/u01/workspace/docker-data/timescale --opt o=uid=root,gid=root --opt o=bind

docker run -d --name timescaledb -p 5432:5432 -v timescale-new:/home/postgres/pgdata/data  timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest
```

I checked my hypertable sizes by below query

```
SELECT hypertable_name, hypertable_size(format('%I.%I', hypertable_schema, hypertable_name)::regclass)/(1000*1000)
  FROM timescaledb_information.hypertables;
```

Which returns total 30 GB. My other non hyper tables are only consuming 1 GB. But the total space my timescale docker volume is taking is 100 GB.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Did you try to [vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html)?